# Filter HTML table rows based on content in other rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table in my HTML website that I'm effectively using as a list to show items.

Each item has:

- an image in column[0]
- a name in column[1]
- a description in column[2]

It is slightly more complicated than that though, column[0] and [2] have a `rowspan="2"` and each item has a second row in the table with it's two categories showing beneath the name in column[1].

This means it ends up looking something like this:- https://jsfiddle.net/vapdp54z/2

I want check boxes somewhere on my website where, by default, none are ticked and all the items show. When a check box is ticked I want all items to hide that don't have the check box content as one of their categories.

I have found similar questions on stackoverflow that do similar things but they don't work for me as in my situation I need to check every other row and when a match isn't found it needs to hide that row and the one above it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your checkboxes looked something like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="CATEGORY1"> Category One<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="CATEGORY2"> Category Two<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="CATEGORY3"> Category Three<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="CATEGORY4"> Category Four <br>
</div>
```

Then you could use their value to hide any table rows with td's containing matching values, and also hide the previous row like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=categories]').click(function() {
        // get the value of the clicked checkbox
        var cat = $(this).val();
        // select odd rows (the ones containing categories)
        $('tr:odd').each(function() {
            // get the td's in the row
            $('td', this).each(function() {
                // if the td html contains the category, 
                // hide its parent row and the previous row
                if ($(this).html().indexOf(cat) > -1)
                {
                    $(this).parent().css('display','none');
                    $(this).parent().prev().css('display','none');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This solution doesn't handle undoing of the hidden rows when the checkbox is unchecked, but that would be fairly simple to do.

Here's a link to the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vapdp54z/3/

I hope this helps!

**EDIT: I Didn't read your question carefully**

If you want to hide all rows that **DON'T** contain that category, just change the > to == in the IndexOf() check